# Custom Animation for Pushing a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, animation, uikit, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to show a custom animation when pushing a view controller: I would like to achieve something like an "expand" animation, that means the new view expands from a given rectangle, lets say [100,100 220,380] during the animation to full screen.

Any suggestions where to start, respectively any documents, tutorials, links? :)

---

Alright. I could make the expand animation with the following code:

```
if ([coming.view superview] == nil)   
    [self.view addSubview:coming.view];
    coming.view.frame = CGRectMake(160,160,0,0);
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"frame" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [coming viewWillAppear:YES];
    [going viewWillAppear:YES];
    coming.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [going viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [coming viewDidAppear:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

My View is properly displayed, but unfortunately the navigation bar is not updated. Is there a way to do that manually?

---

In the sample code, a function is called all 0.03 seconds that updates the transformation of the view.
Unfortunately, when pushing a `UIViewController`, I am not able to resize the frame of the view ...  am I ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you could do is push the next view controller but don't animate it, like so:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:NO];
```

...and then, in the view controller that is getting pushed in, you could do a custom animation of it's view using CoreAnimation.  This might be best done in the `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

Check out the [Core Animation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006085-SW1) on how to actually do the animation. Look particularly at the implicit animation.

**EDIT:** [updated link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html)

Comment: I have tried this approach but the problem is that when you use this push, the first view controller vanishes before the next controller starts animating. What should happen is: 1) the next view controller animates and its view covers completely the old vc's view and then the old vc pops out. I am compiling for iOS 4.3 and this is not working.

Comment: This isn't scalable too. A navigation controller should handle the animating. This is a hack that you would have to implement for every view controller being pushed.

Answer (score 53):

I use the following function (added to `UINavigationController`) to customize the push animation:

```
- (void) pushController: (UIViewController*) controller
         withTransition: (UIViewAnimationTransition) transition
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];        
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I guess you could adapt this code to do whatever animation you want.

Comment: Nice one, how do you handle the popViewController case? from what I can see, tapping the back button doesn't invoke any given target/selector pair even if you overload the back button and provide one, so you can't set it to point to a custom pop method that includes an animation?

Comment: I remember fighting with the custom animations for a while and then going for some less painful solution. I can’t remember what I ended up using, but it was probably something akin to the accepted answer (or I simply gave up and used a factory transition).

Comment: A [category](http://www.google.com/search?q=objective-c+categories) on `UINavigationController` seems like a good place.

Comment: There's an answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3463625/1480438) with this, but I thought I'd mention here that you can easily do the same with `popController`

Answer (score 34):

The code which you are looking for:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:
 UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                       forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:menu animated:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: How to handle popViewController Scenario?

Answer (score 7):

@zoul:  That worked great!  I just changed "self" to "self.navigationController" and "self.view" to "self.navigationController.view"  Don't know if that was necessary, but it worked.  And @crafterm, as for popping back, just make your own leftBarButtonItem by adding this code in viewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear:

```
//add your own left bar button
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Then I just tweaked the push function and made this popWithTransition function that I called in my -backButtonTapped method.

```
- (void) popWithTransition: (UIViewAnimationTransition) transition
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.75];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];        
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.navigationController.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Note that the popViewController call got shifted down to the end, after the animation.  Don't know if that's kosher, but again, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is the downloads for chapter 2 of [iphone developers cookbook](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321555457).  Look at the affineRotate sample specifically, although any of the core animatin samples will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [ADTransitionController](http://applidium.github.io/ADTransitionController/), a drop in replacement for UINavigationController with custom transition animations (its API matches the API of UINavigationController) that we created at Applidium.

You can use different pre-defined animations for **push** and **pop** actions such as *Swipe*, *Fade*, *Cube*, *Carrousel* and so on. In your case, the animation you are requesting is the one called *Zoom*.