# Present model view is not work with uinavigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

i am using navigation based app. i am using push pop for switching view. But when i desire to use present model view controller in order to slide up view..then push pop not work properly?
How can i slideup my view/

Comment: Pls post some code if need some help. I am afraid you are not going to get any like this

Comment: Please post some code example how you push and pop your view controllers on the stack . _Also please remember to mark questions as answered if they were helpful._ If you do not accept any answers other members of SO could get demotivated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the navigationController instance not the View inside.

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:proView animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

This might help...

[Custom Animation for Pushing a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406037/custom-animation-for-pushing-a-uiviewcontroller)

Just implement a custom animation something like:

```
_view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, _view.frame.size.width, _view.frame.size.height);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

_view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _view.frame.size.width, _view.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, the present modal viewer can't be combined with a navigation controller. The present modal viewer is build to do exactly what you want, while the push/pop method gives an easy navigation controller creation...