# How to make a rotate animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i use this code to go to a new nib .

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:statuttableview animated:YES];
```

Can i change the type of animation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Custom animation for pushing a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406037/custom-animation-for-pushing-a-uiviewcontroller).

The modalTransitionStyle is only for presenting modal view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the modalTransitionStyle property on UIViewController.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html