# CALayer with rotation animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer

I have masked an image like this:

```
UIView *maskImage; maskImage = [[UIView alloc] init];
maskImage.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(FTRMaskColor);
maskImage.frame = newFrame;

CALayer *theLayer = [CALayer layer];
theLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] CGImage];
theLayer.frame = newFrame;

maskImage.layer.mask = theLayer;
```

It works fine but the main problem is if I want to rotate the my Ipad, the rotation animation of the view or the layer (I'm not very sure) doesn't work. It rotates without animation. Could you help, please?

Comment: Simply implement rotation animation - [How to make a rotate animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075696/how-to-make-a-rotate-animation)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To rotate a `CALayer`:

```
NSNumber *rotationAtStart = [myLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
CATransform3D myRotationTransform = CATransform3DRotate(myLayer.transform, myRotationAngle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
myLayer.transform = myRotationTransform;        
CABasicAnimation *myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
myAnimation.duration = kMyAnimationDuration;
myAnimation.fromValue = rotationAtStart;
myAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([rotationAtStart floatValue] + myRotationAngle)];
[myLayer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
```

`myRotationAngle` should be in radians. Use negative values for counter-clockwise rotation and positive values for clockwise.

Comment: I can to add a rotate animation to my CALayer but the main problem is the CALayer doesn't rotate during  the rotation of my iPad

Comment: Indeed, this does not answer the question, but it showed up in search results and answered *my* question, so +1 to "This answer is useful" :))

Answer (score 0):

```
        CAKeyframeAnimation *rotation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
        rotation.keyPath = @"transform.rotation";
        rotation.values = @[ @0.14, @0,@0.2 ,@0];
        rotation.timingFunctions = @[
                                     [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut],
                                     [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut],
                                     [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut],
                                     [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]
                                     ];
        rotation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
        rotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        rotation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero;
        [imageLayer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

Answer (score -6):

use CA3Daffinetransform  to rotate