# Stop CABasicAnimation at specific point

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-animation

I'm using a rotation animation created with `CABasicAnimation`. It rotates a `UIView` over 2 seconds. But I need to be able to stop it when the `UIView` is touched. If I remove the animation the view is in the same position as before the animation started.

Here's my animation code:

```
float duration = 2.0;
float rotationAngle = rotationDirection * ang * speed * duration;
//rotationAngle =  3*(2*M_PI);//(double)rotationAngle % (double)(2*M_PI) ;
CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: rotationAngle ];
rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotationAnimation.delegate = self;

[self.view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

How can I stop the `UIView`'s rotation right where it is, when it's touched? I know how to manage the touch part, but I can't figure out how to stop the view at the animation's current angle.

**Solution:**
I solved the problem by getting the angle of the presentation layer, removing the animation and setting the view's transform. Here's the code:

```
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];      
CALayer* presentLayer = self.view.layer.presentationLayer; 
float currentAngle = [(NSNumber *)[presentLayer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(currentAngle);
```

Comment: where did you put the above solution?? I'm always getting angle 0.0000

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Good question! For this, it's helpful to know the Core Animation architecture.

If you check out the diagram in the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) that describes the Core Animation Rendering Architecture, you can see that there's three trees.

You have the *model* tree. That's where you set the values of what you *want* to happen. Then there's the *presentation* tree. That's what is pretty much happening as far as the runtime is concerned. Then, finally is the *render* tree. That's what the user sees.

In your case, you want to query the values of the *presentation* tree.

It's easy to do. For the view that you have attached the animation, get the `layer` and for that `layer`, query the `presentationLayer`'s values. For example:

```
CATransform3D myTransform = [(CALayer*)[self.view.layer presentationLayer] transform];
```

There's no way to "pause" an animation mid flow. All you can do is query the values, remove it, and then re-create it again from where you left off.

It's a bit of a pain!

Have a look at some of my other posts where I go into this in a bit more detail, e.g.

[Restoring animation where it left off when app resumes from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568567/restoring-animation-where-it-left-off-when-app-resumes-from-background/7983292#7983292)

Don't forget also that when you add an animation to a view's layer, you aren't actually changing the underlying view's properties. So what happens? We'll you get weird effects where the animation stops and you see the view in it's original position.

That's where you need to use the `CAAnimation` delegates. Have a look at my answer to this post where I cover this:

[CABasicAnimation rotate returns to original position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683526/cabasicanimation-rotate-returns-to-original-position/7690841#7690841)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the presentation layer. I solved the problem by getting the rotation angle of the presentationLayer with valueForKeyPath:, setting the view's transformation and removing the animation.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the rotation to the rotation of the [presentationLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer) and then remove the animation from the layer. You can read about the presentation layer in my blog post about [Hit testing animating layers](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/21228285860/hit-testing-animating-layers).

The code to set the final rotation would be something like:

```
self.view.layer.transform = [(CALayer*)[self.view.layer presentationLayer] transform];
[self.view.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

Comment: And the position is in the '.position'. Spent several times to realise it. Not obvious for those who knows what OpenGL is.