# CABasicAnimation back to its original position after it finishes its 1 cycle

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cabasicanimation

Don't refer [CABasicAnimation returns to the original position before the next animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511104/cabasicanimation-returns-to-the-original-position-before-the-next-animation) and [Objective-C - CABasicAnimation applying changes after animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515647/objective-c-cabasicanimation-applying-changes-after-animation) and [CABasicAnimation rotate returns to original position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683526/cabasicanimation-rotate-returns-to-original-position)
,I have tried.

The below code does:

bottom->top->goes left->back to its original position.
bottom->top->goes left->back to its original position.

I need:

bottom->top->goes left.
bottom->top->goes left so on…

```objc
- (void)addUpDownAnimationForButton:(UILabel*)label {
    CABasicAnimation * bottomAnimation ;
    bottomAnimation =[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    [bottomAnimation setValue:@"animation1" forKey:@"id"];
    bottomAnimation.delegate = self;
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:)];
    bottomAnimation.duration = 2.0;
    bottomAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:13];
    bottomAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-7];
    bottomAnimation.repeatCount = 0;
    bottomAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    bottomAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [btnSpecialForListing.titleLabel.layer addAnimation:bottomAnimation forKey:@"transform.translation.y"];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation2 finished:(BOOL)flag {
    if([[theAnimation2 valueForKey:@"id"] isEqual:@"animation1"]) {
        CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation;
        moveAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
        moveAnimation.duration=3.5;
        moveAnimation.repeatCount=0;
        moveAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
        moveAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
        moveAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-400];
        moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
        [btnSpecialForListing.titleLabel.layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"transform.translation.x"];
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried this? (Edited)

```
moveAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
moveAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```

**EDIT**
As far as I can see you can also use `animateWithDuration` which has a completion block.
Example would be:

```
CGRect rect = btnSpecialForListing.titleLabel.frame;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

 rect.origin.y = -7;
 btnSpecialForListing.titleLabel.frame = rect;

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

 [UIView animateWithDuration:3.5 animation:^{
 rect.origin.x = -400;
 btnSpecialForListing.titleLabel.frame = rect;
 }];

}];
```

Comment: Yes,i did.
but after completion of 1st cycle only moveAnimation works i.e text only goes left.
but the code for bottomAnimation executes but doesn't display.

Comment: Well you have added moveAnimation to btnSpecialForListing.titleLabel.layer so what exactly you're trying to do? I don't really get it

Comment: see,i have label on which i want to add animation which starts from bottom(bottomAnimation from -7 to -13 position),animation 1 complete then on completion of bottom animation or you can say when bottomAnimation stop our 2nd animation(moveAnimation) starts and goes left.but after completion of moveAnimation my text back to it's original position.and starts once again the same cycle.

Comment: you can try taking label with frame 0,450,320,30.and copy the above code.you will get an idea.

Comment: Thanks...but i got the error read-only variable isn't assignable in  rect.origin.y = -7 line and no known class method error by using animateWithDuration method. 
I am using xcode 5.0

Comment: Hey,It works like charm..You are my hero.. ;) Thank a lot for your valuable time. Cheers !!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2/5:**

```
moveAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
moveAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
```