# different animation for different UIViewController

Tags: animation, uiviewcontroller

I have several UIViewController under a UINavigationController. how would I give different animation in their appearance?

Answer (score 0):

You have a similar question here, what i'm guessing you looking for.

[Custom Animation for Pushing a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406037/custom-animation-for-pushing-a-uiviewcontroller)

PD: Sorry if i'm writing something wrong.