# how to do Facebook like expanding and shrinking animation to view controller

Tags: iphone

how can we add a shrinking and expanding view instead of normal push and pop  for transom between news.i have seen Adems youtube video tutorial for adding shrinking and expanding transition ,but there is no code available for download.how can i implement this to subviews?.is that possible.

Comment: please provide the youtube video tutorial URL.......

Comment: see this url,it may be help to u:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406037/custom-animation-for-pushing-a-uiviewcontroller

Comment: @- Nag_iphone u want youtube ul?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is a popover segue from a UIBarButtonItem, check out these two methods:

```
presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
```