# is there a way to resize the modal view screen in iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios

i ve got a tabbar in one of my views.when a button is clicked in the first tab.it opens a modal view.but the thing is it hides the tabbar bar.what i want is a resized modal view that doesnt hide the tabbar..is it anyway possible?..could you guys help me out.

part of the code

```
if (indexPath.row == 5) {

    if (self.dvController6 == nil) 
    {
        Vad_tycker *temp = [[Vad_tycker alloc] initWithNibName:@"Vad_tycker" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.dvController6 = temp;
        [temp release];
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:self.dvController6 animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Thats the way it works, try adding it as a subView

Comment: that ll complicate things a little bit.coz i neet to add a table view

Answer (score 1):

How about pushing a view controller instead of present modal view controller and change its animation? [Custom Animation for Pushing a UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406037/custom-animation-for-pushing-a-uiviewcontroller)

You have only to manage the "back button" if you are already using a navigation controller or hide the navbar if you don't need it.

Comment: the thing i would have gone for pushing..but ma code is little complicated that it involves another navigation bar.

Comment: is the "modal-pushed" view controller embedded in navigation controller? If so, no problem. You can set hidden=YES the "top" nav bar, and use a UIBarButtonItem in the "embedded" navbar with action like "popViewController" on the "top" navigationController.