# Fade effect when going from one viewController to other using Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

How to achieve fade effect when going from one viewController to other using navigation Controller

normally we do to push :

```
DetailViewController *obj= [[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
```

and to pop :

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

// retain ourselves so that the controller will still exist once it's popped off
 [[self retain] autorelease];

// Pop this controller and replace with another
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But I want fading effect when I do pop or push .. plz suggest

Comment: refer this answer link this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app

Answer (score 1):

this is not the exact code you want but you can get the way how to do the animation you want

First have to pass the parameter `NO` for any animation while push and pop view and have to give some custom animation like this

```
// Flash the screen white and fade it out to give UI feedback that a still image was taken
    UIView *flashView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[self videoPreviewView] frame]];
    [flashView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[[self view] window] addSubview:flashView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4f
                     animations:^{
                         [flashView setAlpha:0.f];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [flashView removeFromSuperview];
                     }
     ];
```

For more detail answer and use the block in proper way see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5889757/1132951) on other question on SO

Some of the code from that answer is as follow

For Push:

```
MainView *nextView = [[MainView alloc] init];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [super pushViewController:nextView animated:NO];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];
```

For Pop:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                         animations:^{
                             [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                             [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
                         }];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Thanks to [@ijordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/737234/ijordan)

Some other tips for the problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1795480/1132951)

[This](https://gist.github.com/3922342) one is one excellent example for your use no use to do extra coding with this as it provides category for animation of navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote [The iOSDev's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12985688) (thanks!) in Swift 5+ (without deprecation warnings etc.):

Push:

```
UIView.transition(with: navigationController.view, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(viewControllerToBeShown, animated: false)
}) { _ in
    completion()
}
```

Pop:

```
UIView.transition(with: navigationController.view, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
    self.navigationController.popViewController(animated: false)
}) { _ in
    completion()
}
```