# Change type of transition when switching view controllers programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm switching view controllers and I want to be able to change the transition when it switches. Currently, it is the default transition, which is cover vertical, and I would like it to be cross dissolve.

Here is the code for switching view controllers:

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController =
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I'd take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406037/custom-animation-for-pushing-a-uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `modalTransitionStyle`

```
secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```